# Dropdown menu in two lines

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Hi I have some troubles while creating a navbar with a dropdown menu, I need all my informations in just one line, but my menu name and the arrow are not on the same.

A CSS element is created : `.dropdown-toggle::after{display: inline-block;}`
[image]

And my navbar looks like this : [image]

I tried the most examples of dropdown/navbars I found on Bootstrap website but every time I have a result displayed in two lines. How can I fix that to have my label and my arrow in the same line?

Comment: where is the code? put code into StackOverflow so we can find the solution from that.

Answer (score 0):

Important Points:

1. If you need all your content in a single line then use `white-space: nowrap;` or reduce the font size.
2. as you mentioned you need the arrow in same line but its not due to less space in there, so use position absolute for the arrow.
3. After making it single line by white-space property you will need to create the ellipsis there so that your content will not look odd.
4. to make ellipsis: use `overflow:hidden;` on its parent and `text-overflow:ellipsis` on your text